# Need the query to check the column type for inserted or deleted Magic tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a trigger for the table which has one Image/Text type column.I know SQL itself does not allow the trigger for Text, NText and Image column.So I decided to audit the table without the above mentioned type column.I dont want to use Instead of Trigger as I am changing one of the existing program which generate the trigger for all the table in my database.

What I want is to `SELECT * FROM [inserted] WHERE (COLUMN type is not TEXT/IMAGE/NTEXT)`

I need the query to check the column type for inserted or deleted table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATA_TYPE  change test_db

```
select DATA_TYPE,*
from test_db.information_schema.columns
order by table_name, ordinal_position

select DATA_TYPE,*
from test_db.information_schema.columns
where  DATA_TYPE = 'TEXT' or DATA_TYPE='IMAGE' or DATA_TYPE='NTEXT'
order by table_name, ordinal_position

select DATA_TYPE,*
from test_db.information_schema.columns
where TABLE_NAME='inserted' and (  DATA_TYPE not in( 'TEXT', 'IMAGE','NTEXT'))
order by table_name, ordinal_position
```

Comment: Does inserted table has the reference in information_schema.columns?

Comment: Yes just run the last query, I leave for you the * just to see the all columns in information_schema  ; where TABLE_NAME='inserted' and (  DATA_TYPE not in( 'TEXT', 'IMAGE','NTEXT')) it is showing only your table If you want to see all tables remove TABLE FILTER where (  DATA_TYPE not in( 'TEXT', 'IMAGE','NTEXT'))DATA_TYPE not